# Expo-Camera not Pausing Preview on Android

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo

[Expo-Camera](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/) not Pausing Preview on Android.

```js
const options = { quality: 0.25, base64: true, allowsEditing: true };
//Props small 0.25, medium 0.5, high 1, by default 0.25

const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);

setSource(data.uri);

await cameraRef.current.pausePreview();
```

This works on iOS but not on Android. Thank you!

Note (this is my first time opening a thread, so any information missing, please just let me know).

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/basic-camera-usage) snack. It works perfectly fine.